# How do i use modules with unreal engine C++

Tags: c++, module, unreal-engine5

I was recently introduced to the concept of modules in unreal engine but i can't seem to get how to use it the way i envisioned it. Okay so what i want to do with modules is spilt functionality into different modules and attach it to the class that is being used in the level. An example will be the character movement component, i want to have it as its own module the attach it to the player character class so it is given that functionality rather than having it inside the character class itself.

I've tried going to youtube but the only thing i see they create a c++ module, create an object from it and use it in the world like that which isn't what i want. I don't want the modules to interact in the engine at all only with the underlying code that i've written

Comment: have you read the documentation? https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/Modules/

Comment: The reason i asked is because the documentation only showed the what to do and left a lot to be desired i was asking because i wanted to also know the why, rather than just blindly follow what they said. But thankfully 

_https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqqQ_wiWYOw&t=12s_

He and copilot came to  the rescue instead and i now understand modules well enough to use it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Ari Arnbjörnsson's video on Modules, but it looks like you already found it.

"module the attach it to the player character class so it is given that functionality rather than having it inside the character class itself"

So this situation, in particular, is handled a little differently than Modules, but a similar concept.  You want to take a look at [Game Features and Modular Gameplay](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/game-features-and-modular-gameplay-in-unreal-engine/) and the Lyra project for an implementation example.  This system supports adding components to specific actors.  A few words of warning: this stuff is much more complex to set up when compared to just adding MyComponent to MyActor, but on par with the complexity of setting up Modules.  Additionally, I want to point out that Character and CharacterMovementComponent, in particular, are very tightly coupled, and a Character is basically a Pawn with a CharacterMovementComponent.